# When user click on url/link then credentials pass over and login automatically.Is there any way to do that

Tags: asp.net, authentication, ldap, single-sign-on

I am currenlty login in my site assume http://www.abc.com that I developed using Asp.net 4.0.

In this site there is url of other site assume http:www/newsite.com

Both sites are using same LDAP Server for authentication

**When user click on url/link(www.netsite.com/person/126) then credentials pass over and login automatically**. No need to login again in other site

Is there any way to login newssite.com automatically after click the url that is on www.abc.com.
You can say user should not need to relogin in newsite.com.because he is already login in
mysite and its credentials shows over url after click

*Both sites using same database for authentication.

Database for authentication is Windows 2008 LDAP Server*

Comment: Hi Terry I update the content

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using an SSO middleware component, for example. But that has nothing to do with LDAP the protocol or the directory information tree. A directory server can be used effectively as a store for SSO and other authentication information, not the SSO mechanism itself.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply.I don't want to change the structure of newsite.com,So SSO is not solution of my problem.One thing is http://usernametmp:pwdTmp@newsite.com that not support all browser(most common)